# How do fetch data from a KML server using Python?

Tags: python, kml, google-earth

Essentially, I am trying to mimic the behavior of Google Earth from a Python script to fetch data from a NetworkLink. Reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#network_links), I see that I need to provide a bounding box using the BBOX variable. However, it seems like I need to request this after an initial request of the data.

Any suggestions on how to ask for this data outside of Google Earth?

Answer (score 2):

Google Earth Pro can be thought of as a specialized web browser that fetches KML and KMZ content in addition to imagery and renders that content in a 3D globe context. Under the covers, Google Earth constructs URLs based on the current view and the KML content such as NetworkLinks. Python code calling a URL in NetworkLink needs to mimic what Google Earth would do to invoke the target URL.

If the target KML [NetworkLink](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink) has *viewFormat* or *httpQuery* elements then the actual URL fetched is updated based on the parameters specified. The *viewFormat* and *httpQuery* define a template with named fields that are filled in with the appropriate values and appended to the URL.

Example NetworkLink definition with target href and viewFormat.

```xml
<NetworkLink>
    <Link>
        <href>http://www.example.com/kml</href>         
        <viewFormat>BBOX=[bboxWest],[bboxSouth],[bboxEast],[bboxNorth]</viewFormat>
    </Link>
</NetworkLink>
```

The string `BBOX=[bboxWest],[bboxSouth],[bboxEast],[bboxNorth]` is a template that will replace the named parameters in brackets for the appropriate values and append the result to the query string of the target URL. The expressions [bboxWest] and [bboxEast] are substituted with the west and eastmost longitude values of the viewing bounding box, [bboxNorth] and [bboxSouth] with the max and min latitude values in the view.

Here is an example of the actual URL that would need to be fetched via HTTP GET request.

```
http://www.example.com/kml?BBOX=-180,-90,180,90
```

List of parameters that can appear in the viewFormat element.

- [lookatLon], [lookatLat] - longitude and latitude of the point that
   is viewing
- [lookatRange], [lookatTilt], [lookatHeading] -
  values used by the  element (see descriptions of `<range>`,
  `<tilt>`, and `<heading>` in [`<LookAt>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#lookat) KML element)
- [lookatTerrainLon],
  [lookatTerrainLat], [lookatTerrainAlt] - point on the terrain in degrees/meters that `<LookAt>` is viewing
- [cameraLon], [cameraLat], [cameraAlt] - degrees/meters of the eyepoint for the camera
- [horizFov], [vertFov] - horizontal, vertical field of view for the camera
- [horizPixels], [vertPixels] - size in pixels of the 3D viewer
- [terrainEnabled] - indicates whether the 3D viewer is showing terrain

More complex NetworkLink example with both viewFormat and httpClient elements.

```xml
<NetworkLink>
    <Link>
        <href>http://www.example.com/kml</href>
        <viewFormat>BBOX=[bboxWest],[bboxSouth],[bboxEast],[bboxNorth];
            CAMERA=[lookatLon],[lookatLat],[lookatRange],[lookatTilt],[lookatHeading];
            VIEW=[horizFov],[vertFov],[horizPixels],[vertPixels],[terrainEnabled];
            LOOKAT=[lookatTerrainLon],[lookatTerrainLat],[lookatTerrainAlt]
        </viewFormat>
        <httpQuery>client=[clientVersion],[kmlVersion],[clientName],[language]</httpQuery>
    </Link>
</NetworkLink>
```

Here is a URL that could be fetched to accommodate the above NetworkLink.

```
http://www.example.com/kml?client=7.3.3.7786,2.2,Google+Earth+Pro,en&
  BBOX=-180,-90,180,90;CAMERA=0,0,0,0,0;VIEW=0,0,0,0,0;LOOKAT=0,0,0
```